# mysql query to find all rows where '+1x' does not equal 'x', ignoring the +1

Tags: mysql, database

Need to find all rows where '+1x' does not equal 'x', ignoring the +1.

For example, a column named *number* contains '+18330001111' and a column named *phone* contains '8330001111' on the same row. The query **SHOULD NOT** return this row because the characters are alike, ignoring the '+1'.

If *number* contains '+183330001212' and *phone* contains '83330001313' the query **SHOULD** return this row because the characters are different, ignoring the '+1'.

Comment: Is it always +1?

Comment: ``TRIM(LEADING '+1' FROM `number`)``.

Comment: It would be better to ask a direct question like: "how compare columns ignoring part of the string?" and then providing the simplest example you can to illustrate your question. You can check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask great questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to normalize the numbers on the fly.

```
select *
from mytable
where replace(phone, '+1', '') != replace(number, '+1', '')
```

The problem here is `replace('+1', phone, '')` nor `replace('+1', number, '')` will not be indexed resulting in a full table scan. If you only have to do this once, that might be ok. If you're doing this often, it's bad, and you should instead normalize the data.

---

Normalizing your data eliminates these sorts of ambiguities and pitfalls. It makes your queries simpler and much faster as they're more able to take advantage of indexing.

In this case, either add or remove (probably add) the country code from your phone numbers. Do normalization on both in the stored data and whatever is inputting data.

```
update mytable
set phone = concat('+1', phone)
where phone not like '+%';

update mytable
set number = concat('+1', number)
where number not like '+%';
```

Now the check is trivial.

```
select *
from mytable
where phone != number;
```